# Unix command to get number of lines in a CSV file

Tags: linux, microsoft-excel, command-line, unix, csv

I have to get the count of lines from incoming CSV files.

I have used the following command to get the count.

```
wc -l filename.csv
```

Consider a file coming with 1 record, I am getting some files with a `\*` at the start, and for those files if I issue the above command it returns count of `0`.

Why is `\*` at the beginning of the file not register as a counted line and is there a work around?

Comment: try "cat filename.csv | wc -l"

Comment: "cat filename.csv | wc -l" logically does the same thing as "wc -l filename.csv" but is less efficient and elegant

Comment: Devoloper250, could you clarify that last paragraph a bit more? An example might help too.

Comment: eg: Iam getting csv files with 1 record which have *(asterisk) in the start of line. When i issue wc -l fn.csv iam getting count as 0 but ideally it should be 1. Does *(asterisk) have any specific thing to do there like other wildcards ??

Comment: What are the results when you run "cat filename.csv"? Also, what distribution are you using?

Comment: Can you update your response with an example file you are processing? Also, does this happen if you have multiple lines that begin with asterisk or only if there is one line?

Answer (score 12):

A trick to ensure that also non-terminated lines are counted may be:

```
cat filename.csv | xargs -l echo | wc -l
```

This seems to count all non-empty lines, but skips empty lines.

Please note that is is rather ineffective, but that is probably not a problem for occational use.

Another possibility, counts all lines including non-terminated last line:

```
awk '{n+=1} END {print n}' filename.csv
```

Tested on RHEL 6.2. YMMV.

Comment: the `awk` command works on OS X

Answer (score 2):

wc will report 0 for files with only one line and no trailing newline. Maybe your one-record csv files are like this? You can look for trailing newlines with hexdump, e.g.:

```
hexdump -C fn.csv
```

Look for ascii code 0a at the end.